# Get Snippets from Bing News Search that are Most Relevant to Query

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-news-search-api

I am using the `https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/news/search?q=Some query` endpoint to search for news articles. The web search endpoint returns snippets from the website that are relevant to the query. Is it possible to get the same for this endpoint?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Are you looking to get web searches returned from the news search endpoint?